# How to initialize a CEvent member in the class declaration?

Tags: c++, mfc, list-initialization

`CEvent` has a single, `explicit` constructor, which accepts zero to four optional arguments.

Is there a way to initialize it as member in the class declaration?
FooBar wouldn't need a written constructor at all if it were possible.

```
class FooBar {
    CEvent e1 = {FALSE, TRUE};
    CEvent e2 = (FALSE, TRUE);
    CEvent e3 = {(FALSE, TRUE)};
    CEvent e4 = CEvent(FALSE, TRUE);
```

None of these alternatives work.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [direct list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) syntax. Remove the `=` operator:

```
class FooBar {
    CEvent e1{ FALSE, TRUE };
    CEvent e2{ FALSE, TRUE };
    // etc
};
```